# Date formatting issue in GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, date-formatting

here is a Date column in GridView in my .net application.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TestDate" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
</asp:BoundField>
```

date displaying properly on my pc in given format :

```
23/03/2011
```

but on test server it displaying in the following format:

```
3/23/2011 5:19:18 PM
```

which is incorrect.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://peterkellner.net/2006/05/24/how-to-set-a-date-format-in-gridview-using-aspnet-20using-htmlencode-property/) that discusses the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 <asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Why htmlencode requires is

```
HTML-encoding field values helps to prevent cross-site scripting attacks and malicious content from being displayed. This property should be enabled whenever possible.
```

Comment: yeah.but on my pc its displaying in the given format properly as i didn't add this attribute on my pc.